# How to convert this trigger to my sql ,this is work for ms sql only

Tags: mysql, triggers

```
create table Items
(
        Number BIGINT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
        ItemNumber VARCHAR(100),
        ItemName varchar(50),
        ItemDescription varchar(50),
        Category varchar(50),
        CreatedDate datetime ,
        Suppiler varchar(50),
        MinOrderQty int,
        unit varchar(50),

)
```

This is my trigger for the table Items:

```
CREATE TRIGGER loadprefix
ON Items
FOR INSERT 
AS 
  BEGIN 
      UPDATE Items 
      SET    ItemNumber = 'ITEM-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, (SELECT Number FROM inserted)) 
      WHERE  Number = (SELECT Number 
                   FROM   inserted) 
  END
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this is defining `ItemNumber` to be the `Number` with a prefix.  Here is one method:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER loadprefix BEFORE INSERT ON items 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    NEW.ItemNumber = CONCAT('ITEM-', NEW.Number)
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thank You very much But it shows their is a syntax error nears to the new ...and i run this on mysql workbench